# send files in a real time Asp.net application

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr

so i'm working on a chat application with signalR. And i want to know if there is a way to send attachement and files ?
I know we can't do that using SignalR but is there another way ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be to use normal Http transfer, and manage the download/upload linking using SignalR,

check out this link:
https://github.com/garethrbrown/aspnet-signalr-upload-progress-bar